# How can I make VS Code go to the end of the line when I press the Tab key?

Tags: visual-studio-code

why i cant press tab key and goes to the end of line code in vscode like other IDE's such as pycharm?

[If i press tab key after type this code it wont go to the end ")"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVra1.png)

[Instead, after type any code if i press tab key something like this happens... vsdeo isnt help me to write code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3ZTf.png)

Ive searched in google how to reset all settings but wont help me

Comment: well, VS Code isn't PyCharm, and its goal is not to be PyCharm. That means it's not going to do everything the same as PyCharm. Why not just use your keyboard's `end` key? (or does your keyboard not have one?)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63042978/11107541