# Looking for a VS Code Extension for Intelligent End-of-Line Cursor Movement Similar to WebStorm

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, webstorm

I've been using WebStorm and am now transitioning to Visual Studio Code for TypeScript and JSX development. One specific feature I miss from WebStorm is the ability to move the cursor intelligently to the end of a line, particularly when working with TypeScript functions and JSX components. In WebStorm, this can be achieved simply by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

For instance, in WebStorm:

When writing a TypeScript function like `const myFunction = () => {`, after auto-completing the closing `}`, the cursor is smartly placed between the braces, and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> moves it to the end of the line.
Similarly, with JSX components like `<MyComponent onClick={() => someFunction()} />`, after auto-completion, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> navigates through the line and eventually takes the cursor to the end of it.

While VS Code handles auto-completion and cursor placement within the line well, it lacks the specific feature of moving the cursor to the end of the line using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Does anyone know of an extension for VS Code that replicates this end-of-line cursor movement as seen in WebStorm? This feature significantly enhances coding efficiency, and I would appreciate any recommendations for a similar tool or extension in VS Code.

Comment: VS Code does do this for snippets with placeholders. Also, the end key is a thing. you can bind `cursorEnd` to whatever you want. I rebind "end" at the OS level to `alt+;`. Also, please read #3 of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: even if you're opposed to the duplicate target I've chosen, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76390527/11107541. you should try to search for duplicates before posting a question. You're expected to do that as part of your research process.

Answer (score 0):

I use TabOut by Albert Romkeys. Seems like exactly what you're asking for!